# How to give out the mode of a list without using the functions: dict, import, count, max, sort, enumerate, sorted

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have to write a program where I have got an input of 10 numbers and the program has to give out the mode of the list, without unsing the functions:

**dict, import, count, max, sort, enumerate, sorted!**

I do not know how I can write the function "count" an "sort" manuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `c` as a tuple that holds `(count, item)`. We can use `iter` to iterate through the values in `lst` and if their count is greater than the previous we can update the tuple to represent that item, after the `iter` is exhausted we print the item from the tuple.

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]

a = iter(lst)
c = (None, None)
while True:
    try:
        b = next(a)
        count = 0
        for i in lst:
            if b == i:
                count += 1
        if c[0] == None:
            c = (count, b)
        elif count > c[0]:
            c = (count, b)
    except StopIteration:
        break

print(c[1])
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If there were no restrictions on the functions or modules you can use, the most efficient way to get the mode of a list is to use the `most_common` method of the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6]).most_common(1)[0][0] # this returns 2
```

But since you are not allowed to use `import`, you can implement the same logic yourself by using a dict (not the `dict` function, but the dict data type) to keep track of the counts of each distinct item, and then iterate through the dict items to find the item with largest count:

```
def get_mode(lst):
    dic = {}
    for item in lst:
        dic[item] = dic.get(item, 0) + 1
    mode, largest = None, None
    for item, count in dic.items():
        if largest is None or largest < count:
            mode, largest = item, count
    return mode
```

so that:

```
get_mode([1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6])
```

would return: `2`